# A basic Object Orientated REPL Implementation

Tags: python, regex, shell

Here is a very basic object orientated implementation of a read evaluate print loop AKA REPL. I encluded `REShell` to demonstrate how one could use `Reple`

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:3
#qpy:console

import re
import sre_constants

PS1 = '>> '

DEFAULT_EVALUATOR = print

class Repl(object):
    def __init__(self, evaluator=DEFAULT_EVALUATOR):
        self.ps1 = PS1
        self.evaluator = evaluator

    def read(self):
        return input(self.ps1)

    def evaluate(self):
        return self.evaluator(self.read())

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                self.evaluate()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                sys.exit(0)


class REShell(Repl):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.ps1 = PS1

    def evaluate(self):
        try:
            expression = re.compile(self.read())
            print(*expression.findall(self.data), sep='\n')
        except sre_constants.error as error:
            print(error)


def source_code():
    with open(__file__, 'r') as source:
        return source.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = source_code()
    print(data)
    shell = REShell(data)
    shell.run()
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks quite good to me! There's some things I think you could improve:

- When a user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, the program flow is suddenly interrupted. The call to `sys.exit` should use `1` as a status code to indicate that something went wrong.
- The REPL prompt is currently hardcoded, but you could easily change `Reple`'s signature to allow a custom prompt:

  ```
  class Reple(object):
      def __init__(self, evaluator=DEFAULT_EVALUATOR, prompt=PS1):
          self.prompt = prompt
  ```

  On that note, `PS1` is a bit ambiguous, maybe rename it to `DEFAULT_PROMPT`.
- This is more of a design argument, but in my opinion it would make more sense to have `run` call `evaluate`, making `evaluator` superfluous; in pseudocode:

  ```
  while true
      read from stdin
      evaluate(expression)
  ```

  And in Python:

  ```
  class Reple(object):
      ...

      def run(self):
          while 1:
              try:
                  expression = input(self.prompt)
              except KeyboardInterrupt:
                  sys.exit(1)
              else:
                  self.evaluate(expression=expression)

      def evaluate(self, expression):
          raise NotImplementedError("This method must be implemented in a derived class")
  ```
- You can use [`abc.ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) together with [`abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) to provide 'truly' abstract methods:

  ```
  import abc

  class Reple(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
      ...

      @abc.abstractmethod
      def evaluate(self, expression):
          return
  ```

  And here's a Python 2 version:

  ```
  import abc

  class Reple(object):
      __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
      ...

      @abc.abstractmethod
      def evaluate(self, expression):
          return
  ```
- You don't have any docstrings, so it's hard to tell what certain methods do or how they should be implemented by subclasses of `Reple`.

Comment: `PS1` is a nod to us Linux hackers. Bash was my introduction to programming. I